# Sending JSONObject in Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

How can I send a `JSON format` like this using `Alamofire 4.2.0` :

This is part from my script :

```
{
 "session":{
     "email": "user1@gmail.com", 
      "password": "secret123"
   }
 }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can just struct your data in `Dictionary` and use `JSONEncoding.default` as encoding to send your request.

```
let mydata: [String: [String: String]] = [
   "session": [
       "email": "user1@gmail.com",
       "password": "secret123"
   ]
]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameter: mydata, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
```